# Occasional Internal Server Errors using Django with mod_wsgi and Apache

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

We are set up using Django + mod_wsgi + Apache.

Cccasionally, whilst we are doing site updates/changing the back-end Python code, site users run into Internal Server Error pages that appear to be served by Apache, not by Django (at least they are the horribly ugly ones, not the nice ones). They do seem to generate error reports though (via email) I think, they just don't seem to land on our 500 server error template.

I'd like to get to the bottom of why this is happening. Normally errors result in the Django-served (and nicely-styled) 500 error page, but just occasionally we see the ugly Internal Server Error page instead.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening and what I can check/test/post here to stop this happening? Help really appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If Apache is showing you the 500 page, that suggests that Django threw an error while rendering the 500 page. For example, there could be a template tag on the 500.html template that Django was unable to render.

Have you looked in your Apache error logs? For Apache2 On Debian they are stored in `/var/log/apache2/` by default. Your operating system may vary.

Comment: Thank you. There are a few tags technically included from the base template, including `{% load analytics %}` and {% if user.is_authenticated %}` - and a few more. I'm guessing these are the guilty culprit. Will try removing them and see if this recurs. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know this behavior, had the same problem on Centos 5.3 with Python 2.5.
After I installed Python 2.7.2 and compiled the latest mod_wsgi (I think it was version 3.3) against it, those errors vanished. The problem is a bug in Python 2.5 as far as I remember in regards to memory allocation.

Be careful when using CentOS, as you can not update Python 2.4, youll have to install versions parallel. Updating Python will break CentOS system features like "yum".

Comment: I'm running Python 2.6 at present - do you have any idea if that also had the bug? If so, I will try this too. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Nope, I don't know if 2.6 has this bug too, but it can't hurt to update python and mod_wsgi anyway.